# SDL2 and KISS_SDL trouble linking on macOS

Tags: c++, macos, sdl

I am having trouble installing and linking KISS_SDL into my C++ project.

I am running macOS v11.2.3 and have installed SDL2, SDL2_image and SDL2_ttf with brew.

Below is the code in main.cpp that will open a simple SDL2 window:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "kiss_sdl.h"


int main()
{
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize the SDL2 library\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2 Window",
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          680, 480,
                                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if(!window)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Surface * window_surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

    if(!window_surface)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to get the surface from the window\n";
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);

    bool isquit = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (!isquit) {
      if (SDL_PollEvent( & event)) {
          if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
              isquit = true;
            }
      }
    }
}
```

Using the terminal command below I attempt to compile and link the required libraries.

```
$ g++ -Wall -o main main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf
```

When I compile without the "#include "kiss_sdl.h"" The program compiles and executes as expected. When I add this include I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:
./kiss_sdl.h:34:10: fatal error: 'SDL.h' file not found
#include <SDL.h>
         ^~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Here is the includes from kiss_sdl.h, I have added a comment in to line 34 where the code is not working:

```
#ifndef _kiss_sdl_h
#define _kiss_sdl_h

#ifndef RESDIR
#define RESDIR ""
#endif

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#elif defined(__APPLE__)
#include <SDL.h>        /* Line 34 */
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#else
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#endif
#include <sys/types.h>
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#include <direct.h>
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#endif
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Why are you using this header at all? It includes the same headers as you already do, and for some reason falls back to SDL 1 on MSVC and Mac (hence the error).

Comment: I am just attempting to include kiss_sdl.h without using it to make sure it compiles before I start coding using it. kiss_sdl is an open source GUI project on GitHub that allows us to create GUI elements with SDL2, the whole project is built on SDL2.

Comment: I guess you could report an issue to the library's author, but since the last release was three years ago I wouldn't hold much hope for a fix. In any case you can probably patch it yourself by replacing the SDL 1 includes with SDL 2 ones.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the issues in the project  https://github.com/actsl/kiss_sdl , issue #21 was started based on this. In brief, this is building using a command line only, without using makefile. But the g++ command line that was used is wrong. In Mac, the headers and libraries are provided by framework, but this is missing in the command line. Because of the framework there is also no need to specify SDL2 directory. This has worked for a number of people using Mac, and the framework is specified in the makefile. This was a short answer, it is going to be tested in Mac, but the person doing that is likely busy and has not enough time for that right now.